# is synchronized needed in getValue() ? & volatile needed?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I've a class in multithreading application:

```
public class A {
        private volatile int value = 0; // is volatile needed here?
    
        synchronized public void increment() { 
          value++; // Atomic is better, agree
        }
    
        public int getValue() { // synchronized needed ?
          return value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"synchronized needed ?"* - no, unless you make `increment` more heavy and dont want `getValue()` to get hands on `value` while `increment` is still executing. *"is volatile needed here?"* - yes, otherwise `getValue()` might read a cached value and not the actual real value (read about happens-before).

Comment: If value is volatile then you don't need synchronized on 'getValue()'. If you use synchronized on 'getValue()' then you don't need volatile since all of your access is via synchronized methods.

Comment: @Zabuzard, Imagine two threads, one calls `increment()`, the other simultaneously calls `getValue()`. The `getValue()` call either will return the value before or the value after the increment. (Am I right?). OK, Now repeat the experiment, only this time, it's `synchronized int getValue()` How is the outcome any different? It is _not_ any different!! `getValue()` either will return the value before or the value after the increment.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Exactly, thats my point... Hence why its obsolete on the `getValue()` in the current state. Until you start making `increment()` a very heavy method that must not be "interrupted". More details in my other comment on Ravindras answer.

Comment: @Zabuzard, OK, but maybe you missed my point. I was reacting to where you said, "unless you...don't want `getValue()` to get hands on `value` while `increment` is still executing." That sounded like you thought there could be some situation in which adding `synchronized` to the `getValue()` method actually _would_ provide a benefit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword `volatile` gives you the visibility aspects and without that you may read some stale value. A volatile read adds a memory barrier such that the compiler, hardware or the JVM can't reorder the memory operations in ways that would violate the visibility guarantees provided by the memory model. According to the memory model, a write to a volatile field *happens-before* every subsequent read of that same field, thus you are guaranteed to read the latest value.

The keyword `synchronized` is also needed since you are performing a compound action `value++` which has to be done atomically. You read the value, increment it in the CPU and then write it back. All these actions has to be done atomically. However, you don't need to `synchronize` the read path since the keyword `volatile` guarantees the visibility. In fact, use of both `volatile` and `synchronize` on the read path would be confusing and would offer no performance or safety benefit.

The use of atomic variables is generally encouraged, since they use non blocking synchronization using CAS instructions built into the CPU which yields low lock contention and higher throughput. If it were written using the atomic variables, it would be something like this.

```
public class A {
    private final LongAdder value = new LongAdder();

    public void increment() {
        value.add(1);
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value.intValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note, in the current state of the code, `synchronized` is only needed on the `increment` method, not on the `getValue` method. It is irrelevant whether `getValue()` reads the value shortly before the update or shortly after the update due to a race condition. You have no control over the timinig on the actual method execution anyways, even with `synchronized`.

Comment: @Zabuzard mixing volatile and synchronized seems more confusing. My preference would be to use synchronized for both methods and remove volatile. That way it's clear both methods use the same lock. (Not saying the other way wouldn't work)

Comment: Well, `synchronized` read is much heavier than a `volatile` read and may degrade the performance in the read path. Therefore, I would rather opt for a volatile read in this case.

Comment: One case where `synchronized` would be needed is for 64b values, such as `long` and `double`, their assignments are not atomic, which means that unprotected read could read corrupted value.

Comment: No, if the 64 bit numeric variable `long` or `double`  is declared `volatile` or guarded by a lock, this issue won't occur according to the Java memory model.

Comment: It is true volatile may be faster, of course it depends on the usage pattern,  but in any case, If we care about performance, it's clear we have better options than either of these. That is why I choose the other option based on readability. Just to explain my Point to view,  this is correct, up-voted.

Comment: Caches are always coherent. Memory barriers have no impact on the caches being coherent. The purpose of a memory barrier it to ensure the order of local load/stores with respect to the global memory order.

Comment: It's arguable. Your claim may be true on modern architectures, but in some older architectures, still a memory barrier may flush or invalidate caches. Even some books written in early 2000s state the same. So, it's subjective and depend on the architecture. But still the essence remains the same.

Comment: I do not know a single mainstream CPU architecture in the last 2 decades that has incoherent caches. So it doesn't make any sense to say otherwise; it just leads to a never ending confusion.

Comment: Also, you are referring to 'lastest' value. This is incorrect. A correctly synchronized Java program (one without data races) only has sequential consistent outcomes. With sequential consistency, a read needs to see the most recent write before it in the memory order, but that doesn't imply wall clock time. So reads and writes can be skewed as long the program order isn't violated (nobody should be able to prove it was violated).